# How to break line / add <br> to ADMIN menu

Tags: wp-admin, admin, admin-menu, line-breaks

Disclaimer: **This question is not about "frontend" nav menu**

I am looking for a way how to break line in a menu item label in WP admin sidebar menu, sidereason is that the custom post type label I am registering is too long for 1 line and I don't really want to mess with the width of the admin menu.

I tried adding both `"\n"` and `<br>` into the custom post type label, but `<br>` gets escaped and line breaks are not converted.

I tried to look on the Internet, but I mainly found articles how to line break in "frontend" menu items which is not what I am looking for.

Is there some sort of filter or other way to do this?

Note: I would also like to avoid tinkering with anything `global` or special characters like nonbreaking hyphen, if possible

**Note2: I know there is auto linebreak in place, however I need a manually added line break because the term is in `some-thing` format so it breaks on dash which is unwanted behavior**

#### EDIT

**Turns out, my problem is specific to the `register_post_type` label,** adding menu item "manually" with `add_menu_page()` does not seem to have this problem, so I am sharing my code for registering the post type:

Please note that, this does reproduce the issue and I also did try putting `label` arg there and removing `labels['name']`(since it overrides `label`) and it produced the same issue.

```
register_post_type("whatever_some", [
    'labels'          => [
        'name'          => 'Whatever a-something',
        'singular_name' => 'Whatever a-something',
        'add_new'       => 'a-something - new',
        'add_new_item'  => 'a-something - new',
        'edit_item'     => 'Edit whatever a-something',
        'all_items'     => 'All whatever a-something',
    ],
    'public'          => true,
    'menu_icon'       => 'dashicons-admin-settings',
    'capability_type' => 'page',
    'hierarchical'    => false,
    'supports'        => ['title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'author'],
    'has_archive'     => true,
    'rewrite'         => ['slug' => 'whatever-asomething'],
]);
```

Comment: What is the label? Note that the admin nav menu wasn't built and styled for this, and in the future it's likely to be replaced by a React/JS based UI. Hints of what that will look like are already showing up in Gutenberg experiments, and an early version of it was adapted for the wordpress.com UI

Comment: @TomJNowell https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/ -`label` this is what I am referring to. What you are saying about react/js based UI implies even more that there probably should be some sort of filter for this which would work regardless of how the UI is implemented :)

Comment: I'm suggesting that this will get harder not easier in the future, and that any filter you did find will probably stop working in the near-mid future. My question wasn't where is the label coming from though, but a literal what is the value of the label? E.g. `"Acme corps example post type label"`. It's difficult if not impossible to explore CSS and JS based solutions without knowing this as there are lots of edge cases and caveats

Comment: It's something like "Whatever a-something" , but "a-something" belongs together as one name and must be placed on a single line. I know a lot of tweaks how to do this, but I was looking for more of an official way. BTW: Very purpose of filters is they're independent of the source code, it would be a real shame if WP core team would abandon that when they already messed up Gutenberg.

Comment: what's the _actual_ label though? Not a generic example, I understood that it ended in a word that had a hyphen from your previous comments.

Comment: I tried to look for the code that escaped the br tags and couldn't find it, then I tried to reproduce your problem but couldn't, the `<br>` tags were preserved with no issues. If you want help you're going to need to share the code so that the problem can be reproduced. Describing the problem and sharing generic examples to hide your code prevents people from helping you

Comment: I am not hiding the code, simply anonymizing the data (I want it to be working in any case anyway), the code is using label in register_post_type. I'm wondering whether I should start a new question, since that's probably other issue if it works for generic admin menus....

Comment: btw: relying on the "actually displayed data" is a very bad practice which I had to fix for clients many times, since the last person who touched the code thought it's a great idea to bind code to e.g. some page's title in specific locale with diacritics...which obviously stops working when ANYTHING is changed.

Comment: You shouldn't run code based on the page title, I'm asking for the actual label because without it I have to do a lot of guessing work. If you had shared the code in your question you would have had an answer by now and avoided the back and forth asking questions. Additionally, CSS based solutions may or may not apply based on the label. Anonymising is hurting not helping you.

Comment: I see where are you coming from, however I simply cannot share certain data (not by my choice). So I chose the most precise way to replicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<br>` tags are not the solution to the problem that you were hoping they would be. Menu labels were never intended to contain arbitrary HTML. HTML does slip through in places, but this appears to be a bug and is inconsistent.

### For Post Types

**No. You can't.**

```php
    $menu[ $ptype_menu_position ] = array( esc_attr( $ptype_obj->labels->menu_name ), $ptype_obj->cap->edit_posts, $ptype_file, '', $menu_class, $ptype_menu_id, $menu_icon );
```

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/270f2011f8ec7265c3f4ddce39c77ef5b496ed1c/wp-admin/menu.php#L169

Changing this would require changes to WordPress itself, and you're likely to face **heavy** resistance.

You *might* be able to use CSS to adjust how overflow occurs, but this will depend on the exact label you used, its length, and the types of characters inside it.

Note that adding a `<br>` to the label would also add it everywhere else that label occurs, causing problems. For example the labels get used in dropdown UI's and as headings.

Oddly enough, the sub-menu labels don't get escaped, so it is possible to add `<br>` tags to sub-menus, although it will lead to unintended problems:

[image]

### For General Admin Menu Pages

You can add `<br>` tags by using them when adding the menu, there is no escaping that removes them. **This is very likely a bug.**

[image]

```php
add_menu_page( 
    'Custom Menu Title',
    'custom menu<br><br>test<br><img width="120" src="https://one.wordpress.test/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Screenshot-2021-04-08-at-20.35.02-1024x564.png" />',
    'manage_options',
...
```

### So What Can I Do?

Ignore `<br>` tags and recognise them as the X Y Problem they were all along. You should have asked how to solve your problem, not how to implement your solution.

By sharing code, an obvious solution appears, use the non-breaking hyphen instead of a normal hyphen:

```
‑
```

[image]

This may not solve the problem for all cases though, after all `super-long-hyphenated-text` will still overflow if given no other opportunities. Fundamentally the label you've chosen is too long. Shortening it is the only reliable and futureproof solution.

Comment: But how come they get escaped when adding through register_post_type? O.o

Comment: you never mentioned `register_post_type` in your question, that is super important information you should have shared. Share your CPT registration code in your question

Comment: I did mention `sidereason is that the custom post type label I am registering` which I thought was implying it, sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: so to make things clearer I've shared `register_post_type` code in **EDIT** replicating the same issue, thank you for your patience :-)

Comment: @jave.web I've updated the answer, it's not good news. `<br>` tags are not the solution you were hoping for.

Comment: thanks, well that's what I feared. Seems like tweaking the `$menu` global (I've suggested I want to avoid in my Q) is the only way x) So you don't need to DIRECTLY touch WP, but you need to touch a core component in a tweaky way which is hardly ever a good thing...

Comment: The non-breaking hyphen is what I would recommend, `<br>` tags are likely to run into other issues in the future related to styling

Comment: Yep, although it's not the "real" hyphen and may be affected by the displaying font (it has different charcode) it may be more reliable.

Comment: WP Admin has a comprehensive font stack that uses system fonts. The situation you described has perhaps a 1 in 10 billion probability of happening if it's possible at all. Perhaps if the user has added a personal stylesheet that uses a font such as wingdings. If it did happen though, most of WP Admin would be broken so nobody would notice the hyphen was missing. As for real hyphens, there are lots of hyphens, `-` is no more or less real than the other options, even extended ascii has `─` which will render on ancient machines from the 80's that don't have GUIs

Comment: those hyphens can have (and have) different meaning and there are some areas in the world where people are especially touchy about those. WP Core team sometimes makes unexpected questionable decisions, so the probability is like 1:100 :-) which is low, I agree. There is a little protection hand of diacritics being used in admin locales. Fonts with latin diacritics tend to have nonbreaking hypen defined.

Comment: In short, dash is not hyphen.

Comment: A non-breaking hyphen is not a dash, it's a hyphen, it's not a character I repurposed because it looks like one, it **is** a hyphen. https://unicode-table.com/en/2011/ _"Non-Breaking Hyphen was approved as part of Unicode 1.1 in 1993."_ It is not a dash. WP Core uses system fonts for max compatibility, rendering a general punctuation character introduced 30 years ago is not a reasonable concern. It would only be a concern for people building sites to run on Windows 95, which isn't capable of running supported browsers

Comment: Also note the `<br>` based solution will not survive the React menu transition, non-breaking hyphens will.

Comment: I know one may "look" like the other, however that varies among fonts. Also it's sometimes a language rule (really like an official rule) or a direct condition of brand mark usage - I am talking 2021, not 1993 :-) (it's probably almost the same in English world, but not in other worlds) Considering there is no reasonable filter, then yes, this will have better survivability if they really go rogue again and redo the whole thing into React :-)